# Deserializing HeaderParam to POJO using Jersey 1.x

Tags: java, jersey

Requests to my application send an `AuthToken` header param.

Is there anyway I can automatically deserialize and decode this into a POJO like below using Jersey?

```
@POST
public Response postSomething(@HeaderParam("AuthToken") AuthToken token) {
    log.info("User " + token.getUser() + " posted something");
}
```

**Note:** I am currently using Jersey 1.x.

Comment: With Jackson this is somewhat easy to achieve with a custom serializer. Is Jackson an option?

Comment: Note: it is likely that you should perform authentication header related operations in a filter, not for each single servlet method :)

Comment: Is there a way I can create a custom deserializer? My AuthToken's are JWT tokens (encoded strings) so I need to write logic to convert them to JSON, which then can be mapped to a POJO

Comment: @dambros I believe Jackson is a part of Jersey so it is definetely an option

Comment: if they're encoded you probably can not get them as objects directly. Then use a filter (;p) and store the decoded object in the request context.

Comment: @Ash could you post an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few possible solutions for Jersey 1.x:

### Creating a constructor

Create a constructor that accepts a single `String` argument in the `AuthToken` class:

```java
public class AuthToken {

    public AuthToken(String content) {
        // Parse the token here
    }

    ...
}
```

### Creating a `valueOf` or `fromString` method

Create a static method named `valueOf` or `fromString` that accepts a single `String` argument:

```java
public class AuthToken {

    public static AuthToken valueOf(String content) {
        // Parse the token here and return an AuthToken instance
    }

    ...
}
```

---

For more details, have a look at [`@HeaderParam`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.18/jersey/javax/ws/rs/HeaderParam.html) documentation for Jersey 1.x:

> Binds the value(s) of a HTTP header to a resource method parameter, resource class field, or resource class bean property. A default value can be specified using the `DefaultValue` annotation. The type `T` of the annotated parameter, field or property must either:
>
> 1. Be a primitive type
> 2. Have a constructor that accepts a single `String` argument
> 3. Have a static method named `valueOf` or `fromString` that accepts a single `String` argument (see, for example, `Integer.valueOf(String)`)
> 4. Be `List<T>`, `Set<T>` or `SortedSet<T>`, where `T` satisfies 2 or 3 above. The resulting collection is read-only.
>
> If the type is not one of those listed in 4 above then the first value (lexically) of the header is used.
>
> [...]